# SQL: Changing structure of sql table with a million rows

Tags: mysql, pivot, innodb

I have a table(lets call it mytable) with the below structure. The table records close to 1 Million rows everyday.

```
id      date      timestamp  licenseid   storeid    deviceid    value
1     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0add      -52
2     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0add      -54
3     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0003       1         0add      -53
4     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0001       1         0add      -54
5     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0002       1         0add      -59
6     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0003       1         0add      -62
7     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0004       1         0add      -55
8     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0bdd      -53
9     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0bdd      -52
10    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0003       1         0bdd      -52
11    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0004       1         0bdd      -50
12    2015-06-12   17:36:33   lic0002       1         0bdd      -54
13    2015-06-12   17:36:33   lic0003       1         0bdd      -54
14    2015-06-12   17:36:33   lic0004       1         0bdd      -55
15    2015-06-12   17:36:33   lic0005       1         0bdd      -40
```

I need to use the same data above and rearrange it in a new table by End of day as below. What sql query should I use to get the below output and store it in new table called 'newtable' considering my table size. The number of licenseids are variable.

```
id   date      timestamp   deviceid  storeid  lic001  lic002   lic003   lic004  lic005.... 
1  2015-06-12   17:36:15     0add      1        -52     -54     -53     
2  2015-06-12   17:36:21     0add      1        -54     -59     -62     -55
3  2015-06-12   17:36:15     0bdd      1        -53     -52     -52     -50 
4  2015-06-12   17:36:33     0bdd      1                -54     -54     -55      -40
```

I need to do so to to perform calculations for each deviceid per timestamp per storeid and arrive at a conversion for each value and finally an unique value for each deviceid per store per timestamp based on a known equation and using individual license values.

Comment: I think you're confusing data display with data storage and retrieval - and 'id' is meaningless in this context.

Comment: You're proposing to *denormalize* your table. If you don't know that term please read about it. Denormalizing is usually harmful in the world of large SQL tables, and is only, barely, justified by very specific performance requirements. The kind of query you're asking for is a *pivot", for your information.  Tell us more about what you're trying to do and the SO community may come up with a good suggestion.

Comment: Also, if you combine your `date` and `time` columns into a single `DATETIME` column and index it, your access that large table will become very much faster.

Comment: I need to do so to to perform calculations for each deviceid and arrive at a conversion for each value and finally an unique value for each deviceid per store per timestamp based on a known equation and using individual license values.

Comment: Search on the `pivot` tag.  Similar things have been asked and answered.

Comment: @Strawberry id is for the primary key for the table

Comment: I'm talking about the result